# Showing Covariance in a 3D graph

Tags: matlab, 3d, covariance

I have a 3D scatter plot and I want to visually show COVARIANCE on it. One can show COVARIANCE, for example with an ISO LINE. With this method, one generally gets an ellipse aligned with the shape of the scatter plot. Do you know how I can do this with MATLAB or any other method.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand how would you like to display covariance on a 3D plot. I think what you are looking for is `pca` , it would give you the three vectors corresponding to maximum variance in your 3D scatter plot. You can then determine the variance along each of those vectors and plot an ellipsoid which represents sort of a confidence region. The final figure would something like this:
[image]

There is a little bit of Linear algebra and rotation matrices knowledge involved with this approach.

Comment: I think this is what what I am looking for. Do you have a sample code which can assist me. I have covariance matrix calculated with me.

Comment: But what I'm saying is this has little to do with the covariance matrix as far as I understand. The axes of the ellipsoid is oriented along the vectors returned from principal component analysis and the radii are the variances along those directions.